# set dropdown value using jquery in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using fancybox and on click of an anchor tag i am opening an iframe as follows:-

```
<a href="/Files/Upload/?personId=@Model.PersonID" class="iframe UpdateLink privilegeLevelIdentityForFile" data-privilegelevelid="@Model.PrivilegeLevelInfoForCurrentUser.PrivilegeLevelInfo.LevelId" title="Upload file(s)">[ + ]</a>
```

The iFrame consist of a form as follows:-

```
<div id="divUploadForm">
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadSpecifiedFileToS3Completed", "Files", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "uploadForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("PrivilegeLevelId", new SelectList((IEnumerable<iNGRID_Data.Security.PrivilegeLevel>)ViewData["PrivilegeLevelsList"], "LevelId", "LevelName"))

    <hr />
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="uploadButton" class="button" />
    </p>
}
</div>
```

I am using the following function while trying to set value of dropdown in iframe

```
$('.privilegeLevelIdentityForFile').click(function () {
    var privilegeLevelId = $(this).data("privilegelevelid");
    alert(privilegeLevelId);
    $("#uploadForm").contents().find('#PrivilegeLevelId').val(privilegeLevelId);
});
```

I am getting the alert correctly but not able to set the value.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `contents()` on the `iframe` element, not the containing `div` within the iframe. Try this:

```
$("#iframeElement").contents().find('#PrivilegeLevelId').val(privilegeLevelId)
```

Obviously, you'll need to change `#iframeElement` as needed.

Comment: Where should this iframeElement be used as an id?

Comment: the iframe id is fancybox-frame and when i try using the code you posted it is still not working.